# Dependency Injection of service in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I am migrating a large Vue 2 codebase to Vue 3.
In Vue 2 , we used to use inversify-props. While migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3 , I tried to stick to inversify-props but it is not working as expected.

it seems the inject() decorator is not working in Vue 3.

Our existing codebase is heavily dependent on dependency injection of services which we achieved using inversify-props.

WHat should be the best option to migrate those dependency injection of services with minimal effort ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, inversify-props doesn’t support vue 3 yet, you may consider switching to vue 3 [provide & inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) if you want to use vue 3.

I found a GitHub repo with the implementation of inversify with vue 3 maybe it can help you: [vue3-inversify](https://github.com/yogurt1/vue3-inversify)

overall, all available solutions need a lot of work :(